# xlabels only appear formatted in one of two subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis-labels, subplot

I would like to plot 2 figures with the subplot function and with two different x axis (datetime format).

I did the following code :

```
fig=plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MinuteLocator())
plt.plot(WaveLab_df['Time'],WaveLab_df['Active_Power_Starboard_W'])
plt.plot(WaveLab_df['Time'],WaveLab_df['Active_Power_Portside_W'])
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(df_tempS['DateTime'],df_tempS['Power[W]'])
```

and I obtain :
[image: My Figure]

The fact is that in the second plot I would like to have the same type of x label (hour-minute). I want for each plot the x axis.

I tried different combinations but I wasn't succesfull.

Does anyone as an idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the formatter and the locator on *both* of your subplots.

```
fig=plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MinuteLocator())
plt.plot(WaveLab_df['Time'],WaveLab_df['Active_Power_Starboard_W'])
plt.plot(WaveLab_df['Time'],WaveLab_df['Active_Power_Portside_W'])
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(df_tempS['DateTime'],df_tempS['Power[W]'])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MinuteLocator())
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to call this line again after you open the second subplot.

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: It is a bit better, now I have on my second plot 3 values in the good format (19:45:00; 19:50:00; 19:55:00).

Comment: Okay finally I have decided to write the two lignes : 
`plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))`
`plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MinuteLocator())`

And I have only one x axis but with the time in minutes so it is quite okay. 
I do not validate the answer so that someone can answer if he finds the good answer. 
Thanks

Comment: @Nathan But isn't that already "the good" answer? What else do you expect?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I would like to have the values of the x axis on both figures. Now I have only it Under the second figure. It is okay because the time series should be the same but if in any case it is not the same, I don't know what will happen.